# Windows 10 Updates

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to buy Windows 10, but without any major update (technical LTSB version), but it!s not legal for home user. Can I make some changes in Windows (legal) which I can make them something like LTSB (only security updates no new features)?

Edit for possible duplicate: I want ONLY security updates. No new features at all.

Comment: There are several methods to disable Windows Update on Windows 10.  However, there isn't any way to convert Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional into an LTSB Enterprise version of Windows.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, cause I want ONLY security updates, but no new features.

Comment: Pro Windows 10 Professional can always be purchased and installed on a home PC.  Just more expensive.

Comment: @Lanki - There are multiple solutions, contained within answers to that question, that work for Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional and provide a mechanic to control when and if you receive an update.  If you want to the ability to defer feature updates and cumulative updates (which contain the security updates you want to install), then your only option is to use WSUS and install them manually or upgrade to Windows 10 Professional.  What you want is not possible, with any version of Windows, so my suggestion is to use WSUS and avoid windows update all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no legal and offical way to disable system updates in the Windows 10 Home Editions! Only with [hacks](https://www.google.com/search?ei=6X7sWvStGIWRsgH664CYCQ&q=windows%2010%20home%20disable%20automatic%20updates&oq=windows%2010%20home%20disalbe%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i13k1l3j0i13i30k1l3j0i13i10i30k1j0i13i30k1l2j0i13i10i30k1.15998.18620.0.20746.15.10.0.0.0.0.884.1246.3-1j6-1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..13.2.1242...0.0.ALOk4H2Vf78) etc. (which you find after a small google reserach) it's possible. Well, microsoft don't likes it and fixes it from update to update. And also modifications on your system like these make your computer may unsecure.

Only just Windows 10 Pro Edition allows you to disable (delay until specific period) all updates besides important securtiy updates.

And the Enterprise and (possible) the Education Editions allow fully to disable all kind of updates forever!

Comment: It's really annoying, that home user can't make an own decision about his system. I hope Microsoft will make some special version for us, home users.

Comment: The home versions IS the special version for home users.  It is purposeful the way it is setup.

Comment: @Damon At least at Enterprise its possible!